# Blank screen after deploying react app on Vercel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, deployment, vercel

My package.json file where I also tried including the previous solutions "homepage"... in this

Any syntax mistakes or references I mistakenly added here in here ? My build was successful but all I could see i a blank page in my deployed site

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^19.2.55",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "mdbreact": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-calendar": "^3.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-minimal-side-navigation": "^1.9.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "rsuite": "^4.10.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "homepage": "."
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My App.js file where I imported all my React and Redux Routers..

```
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import FoodCatalog from "./Components/Pages/FoodCatalog";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Promotions from "./Components/Pages/Promotions";
import UserManagement from "./Components/Pages/UserManagement";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import reducer from './redux/reducers'
import Tickets from "./Components/Pages/Tickets";



function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Sidebar />
        </div>

        <div style={{width: '100%',overflow: 'hidden'}}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/foodcatalog" component={FoodCatalog } />
            <Route path="/promotions" component={Promotions } />
            <Route path="/usermanagement" component={UserManagement } />
            <Route path="/tickets" component={Tickets } />
          </Switch>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is this happening when building the application and serving it (e.g. using `serve`)

Comment: it builds successfully but I could see only a blank page

Comment: So it has nothing to do with vercel

Comment: I am having the same issue. changing the homepage value in package json has not helped.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing the same problem while deploying react apps to Vercel, adding `"homepage": "."` to **package.json** worked for me. I was initially using **gh-pages** but wanted to shift to Vercel and hence I completely removed the homepage settings because of which I was getting a blank screen after visiting the deployed URL on vercel. So I added that homepage setting and finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Specifiying “homepage”

If you’re using create-react-app, you won’t have to deal with Webpack configs. (Which is nice) Instead – ejected or not –  we just have to specify “homepage” in our package.json:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ5WW.png)

The way how create-react-app has it’s webpack configuration set up, this will replace the publicPath with the correct base URL for your app. (If you want to know more about the publicPath setting,  have a look at the Webpack documentation)

Refer this: https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-whitescreen-static-react-app/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into your vercel environment variables and putting:

```
CI=false
```

Sometimes vercel needs that environment variable in production.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the comment. Yes., I did it in settings to troubleshoot my build error. I'm ok with building. Just the blank screen is troubling me.